# Should I Compare CComBSTR to NULL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com

In following code snippet,

```
CComBSTR bstrVal;
HRESULT hr = GetVal(bstrForest);
if (bstrVal!= NULL || bstrVal.Length() > 0)
{
    …

}
```

Is the check `bstrVal!= NULL` is a valid check as `bstrVal` is a object of a class?
I can see in Visual studio the value of `bstrVal` becomes `NULL` if it is not initialized.

Please explain.

Comment: You can do it, but it's useless

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`CComBSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) have an overloaded [`operator!=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350c0fa0.aspx) function, which among others take an integer. And in C++ `NULL` is a macro which is expanded to the integer value `0`.

That means you're not really comparing the `bstrVal` *object* to `NULL` (which it will never be) but rather calling the `operator!=` overload, passing zero which is explicitly allowed.

That means the comparison is fine.

Comment: The comparison may be fine, but `CComBSTR` also defines [`operator!`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx#ccombstr__operator__not) and [`operator BSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx#ccombstr__operator_bstr), which should be used instead when comparing to NULL, eg: `if ((bstrVal) && ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a `CComBSTR` against NULL is legal in your example, as `CComBSTR` overrides `operator!=` to support NULL as an input value (but there are better options available to check if the `CComBSTR` has a non-NULL `BSTR`).

However, if you are only interested in a `BSTR` whose length is > 0 then the check for NULL is redundant:

```
CComBSTR bstrVal;
HRESULT hr = GetVal(&bstrVal);
if (bstrVal.Length() > 0)
{
    …
}
```

`CComBSTR::Length()` is a wrapper for [`SysStringLen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221240.aspx), which returns 0 for a NULL `BSTR`.

In your example, your `if` is entered if the `BSTR` is allocated, even if it has 0 characters in it. You probably meant to use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if (bstrVal != NULL && bstrVal.Length() > 0)
```